# Xcode 5 - Can no longer validate archives

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I upgraded from Xcode 4 to 5 and I can no longer validate archives created for Ad-Hoc distribution.

After creating an archive, I hit Validate, log into iTunes Connect (as prompted) and get the error "No identities are available for signing":

[image]

If I click 'Download Identities...' then pick my team name (me) it just takes me back to this error prompt.

**Specifics**

- I have created and signed an Ad Hoc distribution profile called 'survey_dist_9'
- The Code Signing settings in my Target look like this, although I have tried many combinations of these profiles:

[image]

- My unchanged, existing project that worked fine in Xcode 4 no longer works in Xcode 5. I validated 15 versions of my app without fail before upgrading to XCode 5.
- In My Xcode organizer it shows no provisioning profiles except under my iPad device. Has this changed since Xcode 4? (Sure they used to be there)

There are similar sounding questions here but the solutions I've found are not applicable.

No crashes are occurring as described in similar sounding questions. I can distribute as Ad Hoc. The problem is we're using Ad Hoc as a production solution (distributing an in-house app to a small company) so I'm reticent to skip the Validation process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to preferences| accounts make sure xcode is connected to your apple dev account.

Comment: @Mojtaba Checked that - it is. 'View details' shows I have 2 signed identities (development and distribution) and a bunch of provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the bundle identifier in Xcode matches your App's bundle ID in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, follow the screens below, it should help you..

[image]

[image]

[image]

And yes they have removed Profiles from Organizers, instead you can use **iPhone Configuration Tool**.

Hope it helps..

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have the 'Team' set. However now I've done that it still doesn't work - same problem at validation attempt. Where you say 'Select Certificate' that should be my iPhone Distribution identity right?

Comment: I think after adding the Team you can try Import Developer Profile, then after its done, check your profile again, then proceed..

Comment: Sadly no. Both 'Import Developer Profile' and 'Download Identities' > [Select me] both redirect me straight back to the 'No identities are available' error page with no reason given.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple disabled the ability to validate with **just** an ad hoc provisioning profile in XCode 5.

If you wish to validate an app that is intended **only** for Ad Hoc distribution, you must also have an App Store provisioning profile for the app too, against which to validate it.