# Cant find identities for app store submission

Tags: ios, xcode5

Ok, I know this sounds stupid, but im trying to upload a new version of my app to the app store. I updated the app to run on iOS 7, i upgraded to Xcode 5 and i also changed macs since my last submission. I created the archive, but every time it tries to validate, i get this error:

[image]

I have all of the valid certificates and profiles. When i try to import a developer profile, i do have 1 option but i sadly forgot the password for it :/

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you have the old mac to export the certificate again?

Comment: Try look my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822101/xcode-5-can-no-longer-validate-archives/19822755?noredirect=1#comment29474994_19822755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i was able to get it to work thanks to the comment left by @iphonic ([Xcode 5 - Can no longer validate archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822101/xcode-5-can-no-longer-validate-archives/19822755?noredirect=1#comment29474994_19822755)). I had to change the code signing identities and profiles from 'development' to 'distribution' and made sure they were all matching.